# Pointer is all odd after update

Tags: 11.10

I just did the pushed "important security update"s and now my pointer is an odd string of small black dots. I can't find any way to change it and it is making the system difficult to navigate. (11.10)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried logging out and back on?  This should refresh variables and settings in either Gnome or Unity.

Comment: Yes, tried that twice.

Comment: What Window Manager are you using?  Gnome? Gnome-Shell? Unity? are you running Compiz at all?

Comment: only what comes with 11.10